# Image of a curve by a transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, transformation

Given the curves:

1. $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$
2. $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Find the images by the transformation $w(z)=1+e^{-z}$

**What I did**

First decompose the tranformation function $w(z)$ into $w(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. So,$$u(x,y)=1+e^{-x}\cos y$$ $$v(x,y)=-e^{-x}\sin y$$
Then, for the first curve $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ it's possible to find the relation $$(u-1)^2+v^2=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
This is a circle in the uv-plane.

For the other curve, find the relation $$v=-u+1$$ .

**My question is if I define an orientation to the curves how the orientation changes when the transformation is applied?**

Comment: What do you mean by orientation, exactly? For example as you are mapping $z$ to $e^{\color{red}{-}z}$, left to right is mapped to clockwise. But left to right is neither positive nor negative

Comment: For example, I can define an orientation to curve $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ just letting y vary from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (going upwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parameterize the first curve as
$$
 \gamma(t) = \frac \pi 4 + it \, , \quad t \in \Bbb R
$$
then
$$
 w(\gamma(z)) = 1 + e^{-\frac \pi 4 - it} = 1 + e^{-\frac \pi 4} (\cos(t) - i \sin(t)) \, .
$$
Therefore if $t$ increases, $\gamma(t)$ moves “upwards” and $w(\gamma(z))$ rotates on the circle $|z-1| = e^{-\frac \pi 4}$ in a clockwise direction.

A similar approach can be used for the second curve.